# Doctrine2 cannot load class with namespace through relationship

Tags: php, oop, namespaces, doctrine-orm

I've got 2 entities; BusinessContactInformation and ContactInformationTypes. One entity of BusinessContactInformation is always of a given ContactInformationType.

However, when I try to load an entity of the type BusinessContactInformation, I get this error:

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/tmp//_*CG*_platformentitiesContactinformationtypes.php'

The entities are both in the \platform\entities namespace, and they have the following annotations:

```
/**
 * Businesscontactinformation
 *
 * @Table(name="businessContactInformation")
 * @Entity
 */
(...)
/**
 * @var Contactinformationtypes
 *
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Contactinformationtypes")
 * @JoinColumns({
 *   @JoinColumn(name="contactTypeId", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $contacttypeid;
```

And Contactinformationtypes:

```
 /**
  * Contactinformationtypes
  *
  * @Table(name="contactInformationTypes")
  * @Entity
  */
```

Does anyone have a clue to what's causing this? I'm having this with *ALL* of my relationships - one to many, many to one, ... .

Answer (score 0):

I ended up regenerating my entities and proxies. It allowed me a proper fresh start, and i had to point to my proxies as a third parameter in Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration.